# Which Structuremap Lifecycle is best practice? (v2.5.4)

Tags: structuremap

which of the following syntax is considered best practice?

```
For<IMyInterface>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle()).Use<MyImplementation>();

For<IMyInterface>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.Hybrid)).Use<MyImplementation>();
```

if the first one is correct, can I create one object HybridLifecycle, and use it for multiple For<...> statements, or is it necessary for each For<> to create a new HybridLifecycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the configuration helpers is probably the best practice.

```
    For<IMyInterface>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<MyImplementation>()
```

Comment: not alle scopes are provided as helpers, only HYbridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped and HttpContextScoped ..

Comment: I believe they are which ones are you not finding? Singleton(), AlwaysUnique() are also available. I think Jeremy may be trying to move people to the Hybrid approaches to HTTP and Thread scoping of types.